# text disappears rapidly after click on 'submit-button'

Tags: javascript

Got a problem. this is my code:

```
<html>

<body>
<form>
<p>13-7: <input id="in1" type="text"" /><input type="submit" onclick="check(6, 'in1', 'out1')" value="Tjek!"/></p>
<p id="out1"></p>
<p>20-7: <input id="in2" type="text"" /><input type="submit" onclick="check(13, 'in2', 'out2')" value="Tjek!" /></p>
<p id="out2"></p>



<script type="text/javascript">

function check(facit, input, output) {
    var answer, evaluation;
    answer = document.getElementById(input).value;
    evaluation = (answer == facit) ? "Correct" : "Wrong";
    document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = evaluation;
    return false;
}

</script>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click the submit-button, the 'correct/wrong' shows only for a moment. I want it to stay on the site, any advice?

Comment: Just get rid of the opening *form* tag, the closing tag is missing and it seems you aren't using the form for anythying useful anyway. The controls don't have names so can't be successful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The submit buttons are submitting your form (so reloading your page).

Change the buttons to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 3):

Your buttons are submit buttons (`<input type="submit">`) so they will submit the form and refresh the page on each click. Change your buttons to `<input type="button">` instead.

Comment: when i click submit, does it submit the entire form?

Answer (score 2):

Change the onclick function from:

```
onclick="check(13, 'in2', 'out2')"
```

to:

```
onclick="return check(13, 'in2', 'out2')"
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the form to be submitted, as you have two Submit buttons, it is better to use:

```
<input type="button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change onclick from this

```
onclick="check(6, 'in1', 'out1')"
```

to

```
onclick="check(6, 'in1', 'out1'); return false;"
```

Do the same way for the other one too.

Remove `return false;` on the `check` function.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/QUdLP/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The form is being submitted and returned with the original page.

What do you want to do?

```
I dont want it returned with the original page .. I want it to say 'correct' og 'wrong' below the input
```

If you don't want to submit the data then do as minitech suggests, change the type from submit to button.

If you want to save the data you will need to write server side code and then create html with those values filled in (on the server side.)

Comment: I dont want it returned with the original page .. I want it to say 'correct' og 'wrong' below the input